# Is there something similar to seaborn stripplot in mathematica

Tags: plotting

Is there something similar to seaborn stripplot in mathematica?
The graph I am trying to make is like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you have any sample data that can be used by people who want to try things out?

Answer (score 14):

This can be done with `DistributionChart` and a bit of programming:

```
data = Table[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1], 30], {7}];

DistributionChart[data, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartElementFunction -> "PointDensity"]
```

[image]

```
DistributionChart[data, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartElementFunction -> ({AbsolutePointSize[5], 
     Point[Transpose[{RandomReal[#1[[1]], Length[#2]], #2}]]} &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just adding OP's styling to @BrettChampion's answer:

```
 data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 10], 
 RandomInteger[{10, 100}]], {4}];
 DistributionChart[data - Min@Flatten@data, BarSpacing -> 2, 
 AspectRatio -> 1.5, PlotRange -> {{1/2, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}, 
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Day", "Total_Bill"}, 
 GridLines -> {{}, 10 # & /@ Range[0, Max@Flatten@data]}, 
 ChartLabels -> {"Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ({AbsolutePointSize[5], 
 Point[Transpose[{RandomReal[#[[1]], Length[#2]], #2}]]} &)]
```

[image]